# Laravel 5.2 hosting : Parse error

Tags: laravel, hosting, parse-error

I am new in Laravel framework . I want to upload my simple locahost laravel 5.2 project to server. My site name is studentfair.net and in its cpanel it has no ssh option in security panel. So i upload my full project folder by filezilla .
When i enter studentfair.net/public then it was show me an error

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/studentfair/public_html/public/index.php on line 50
```

[image]
[image]

So how can I solve this problem and show my index.blade.php properly without any command line. thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you edit the lines in question into the question? Say, lines 47-53

Comment: i dont understand your comment pekka sir :(

Comment: Can you show us lines 47 through 53 in your index.php file? (because the error is in line 50)

Comment: $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

Comment: Can you edit it into the question so we can see which line is line 50?

Comment: its solved boss =D . thanks